# How to retrieve a webpages sitemap

Tags: c#, web-crawler, console-application

I am trying to create a content scraper that would scrape a page and its subpages.
**My main goal** here Is that I need to retrieve a webpages subpages if it has any.

To demonstrate what I would like is pretty much what this [website does](https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/)

At first thought I tried to create this pseudo code:

```
1. Crawl Url
2. Check A-tags Values(href) and add to list
 - if the value contains in visited links ignore
3. Take new Values and turn them into possible URLs 
4. Add those into new NewUrls List
5. Crawl NewUrls
6. Keep Track of visited URLs 
7. Visit newUrls do nr 1.
8. Stop when visited URL equals to newUrl
```

So the **problem** here:
On the **3rd** task I have to put the URL through multiple different Rules, that it still has the baseHost inside it, doesn't contain unnecessary items and so on.

Since there can be continuous amounts of different styled href values this will have to have quite many rules and checks, which let alone makes it looks messy but also makes it really slow.

Is there a better way to retrieve a sites sitemap? 
Or to put it easily, how could I retrieve all subpages of a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since there can be continuous amounts of different styled href values this will have to have quite many rules and checks, which let alone makes it looks messy but also makes it really slow.

You can use this [uri constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Uri__ctor_System_Uri_System_String_) to deal with this:

```
public Uri (Uri baseUri, string relativeUri);
```

The base uri will be the Uri of the page you're currently on. Relative Uri will be the href value. Then you can check if the result has the same host as the base uri.

This solves common issues like relative urls and http/https variations in links.

You can also consider removing query string from the Url. This is a common source of duplicate urls but some websites may use it for functionality.

Comment: This is good But I found one problem is that IF i were to have a facebook or any other links that Differ from the hosturl it adds them to the list aswell, how would be the best way to filter out links that differ from the host url?
Example if my list were:
https://facebook.com/host
https://hosturl.com/
I would need it to discard facebook..
My inital thought was to check if the new url contains the hosturl but then i cant get the items that just contain "page" or "/subpage"

Comment: You can simply compare the hostname. `baseUri.Host == hrefUri.Host`